# UI5 - TreeTable with XML Model Rendering Issue

Tags: javascript, xml, treeview, sapui5

I am currently construting a tree table in XML view with XML Data Model.

Following is My XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Rowsets>
    <Rowset>
        <Row>
            <root>
                <id>root</id>
                <level>root</level>
                <children>
                    <id>01</id>
                    <level>01</level>
                    <name>Case Packer</name>
                    <children>
                        <id>0101</id>
                        <level>0101</level>
                        <name>Unscheduled</name>
                    </children>
                    <children>
                        <id>0102</id>
                        <level>0102</level>
                        <name>Lunch</name>
                    </children>
                    <children>
                        <id>0103</id>
                        <level>0103</level>
                        <name>Scheduled Operations</name>
                        <children>
                            <id>010301</id>
                            <level>010301</level>
                            <name>Cleaning</name>
                        </children>
                        <children>
                            <id>010302</id>
                            <level>010302</level>
                            <name>Major Changeover</name>
                        </children>
                        <children>
                            <id>010303</id>
                            <level>010303</level>
                            <name>Paid Break</name>
                        </children>
                        <children>
                            <id>010304</id>
                            <level>010304</level>
                            <name>Running Production</name>
                            <children>
                                <id>01030401</id>
                                <level>01030401</level>
                                <name>Lowrater</name>
                            </children>
                            <children>
                                <id>01030402</id>
                                <level>01030402</level>
                                <name>Labeler 1</name>
                            </children>
                            <children>
                                <id>01030403</id>
                                <level>01030403</level>
                                <name>Depalletizer</name>
                            </children>
                            <children>
                                <id>01030404</id>
                                <level>01030404</level>
                                <name>Filler</name>
                            </children>
                            <children>
                                <id>01030405</id>
                                <level>01030405</level>
                                <name>Bottle Coder</name>
                            </children>
                        </children>
                    </children>
                </children>
            </root>
        </Row>
    </Rowset>
</Rowsets>
```

Following is My XML View:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<core:View 
    xmlns:core="sap.ui.core" 
    xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc"
    xmlns:l="sap.ui.layout"
    xmlns="sap.m" 
    xmlns:t="sap.ui.table" 
    controllerName="treetabledemo.TreeTableDemo"
    xmlns:commons="sap.ui.commons" 
    xmlns:common="sap.suite.ui.commons"
    xmlns:h="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <Page showHeader="false" enableScrolling="false" class="donuts">
        <l:Splitter orientation="Vertical">
            <l:contentAreas>
                <Page title="TreeTableDemo">
                    <content>
                    <t:TreeTable id="idProductionTable" rows="{path:'/Rowsets/Rowset/Row/root', parameters: {arrayNames:['/children']}}">

                            <t:toolbar>
                                <Toolbar>
                                    <Title text="Production"/>
                                </Toolbar>
                            </t:toolbar>
                            <t:columns>
                                <t:Column width="130px" demandPopin="true" id="idProdReportNode" showSortMenuEntry="false"
                                                         minScreenWidth="Tablet">
                                    <Label text="NAME" design="Bold" class="TableLabelColor" />
                                    <t:template>
                                        <ObjectIdentifier text="{name}" />
                                    </t:template>
                                </t:Column>
                                <t:Column width="130px" demandPopin="true" id="idProdReportProdCount" showSortMenuEntry="false"
                                                        minScreenWidth="Tablet" hAlign="End">
                                    <Label text="Level" design="Bold" class="TableLabelColor" />
                                    <t:template>
                                        <ObjectIdentifier text="{level}" />
                                    </t:template>
                                </t:Column>
                            </t:columns>
                        </t:TreeTable>
                    </content>
                </Page>
            </l:contentAreas>
        </l:Splitter>
    </Page>
</core:View>
```

Following is my controller:

```
sap.ui.controller("treetabledemo.TreeTableDemo", {

onInit: function() {

    var sPath = "resources/data/treedata.xml"; 
    var oModel = new sap.ui.model.xml.XMLModel(sPath);
    var that = this;

    var oTable = this.byId("idProductionTable");
    oTable.setModel(oModel);    

    },

});
```

But it gives me following error:

```
Uncaught Error: Path path:'/Rowsets/Rowset/Row/root', parameters: {arrayNames:['/children']} must start with a / 
    at d.a.getContext (sap-ui-core.js:1549)
    at f.c.applyFilter (sap-ui-core.js:1381)
    at f.c.checkUpdate (sap-ui-core.js:1386)
    at f.B.initialize (sap-ui-core.js:1313)
    at f.h._bindAggregation (sap-ui-core.js:511)
    at f.z._bindAggregation (Table.js:6)
    at f.h.updateBindings (sap-ui-core.js:517)
    at f.h.setModel (sap-ui-core.js:528)
    at constructor.onInit (TreeTableDemo.controller.js:15)
    at f.a.fireEvent (sap-ui-core.js:449)
```

I tried various permutations and combinations but it does not seem to work.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For XML Models the root must not be included in the path. You should remove the **/Rowsets** from the binding path as documented [here](https://help.sap.com/saphelp_uiaddon10/helpdata/en/b8/a2c24356c443228f7819d45697a2b8/content.htm).

So th path should be

```
rows="{path:'/Rowset/Row/root', parameters: {arrayNames:['/children']}}"
```

However you will now have a second problem, for your TreeTable will look something like this.
[image]

This is because XML models will work differently as compared to a JSON model which makes the binding path syntax somewhat difficult.

```
<children>
                <id>01</id>
                <level>01</level>
                <name>Case Packer</name>
                <children>
                    <id>0101</id>
                    <level>0101</level>
                    <name>Unscheduled</name>
                </children>
</children>
```

In the above, the model will consider the root children node to have 4 child nodes. To fix this, the id, level & name should be attributes of the children object.

So your treedata.xml should be  something like this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Rowsets>
    <Rowset>
        <Row>
            <root id="root" level="root">
                <children id="01" level="01" name="Case Packer">
                    <children id="0101" level="0101" name="Unscheduled" />
                    <children id="0102" level="0102" name="Lunch" />
                    <children id="0103" level="0103" name="Scheduled Operations">
                        <children id="010301" level="010301" name="Cleaning" />                                                                               
                        <children id="010302" level="010302" name="Major Changeover" />                                                                               
                        <children id="010303" level="010303" name="Paid Break" />                                                                               
                        <children id="010304" level="010304" name="Running Production">                                                                               
                            <children id="01030401" level="01030401" name="Lowrater" />                                                                                
                            <children id="01030402" level="01030402" name="Labeler 1" />                                                                                
                            <children id="01030403" level="01030403" name="Depalletizer" />                                                                                
                            <children id="01030404" level="01030404" name="Filler" />                                                                                
                            <children id="01030405" level="01030405" name="Bottle Coder" />                                                                                
                        </children>
                    </children>
                </children>
            </root>
        </Row>
    </Rowset>
</Rowsets>
```

With this you can bind the attributes as {@id}, {@level}, {@name}

```
 <t:TreeTable id="idProductionTable" rows="{path:'/Rowset/Row/root/', parameters: {arrayNames:['/children']}}">

                        <t:toolbar>
                            <Toolbar>
                                <Title text="Production"/>
                            </Toolbar>
                        </t:toolbar>
                        <t:columns>
                            <t:Column width="130px" demandPopin="true" id="idProdReportNode" showSortMenuEntry="false"
                                                     minScreenWidth="Tablet">
                                <Label text="NAME" design="Bold" class="TableLabelColor" />
                                <t:template>
                                    <ObjectIdentifier text="{@name}" />
                                </t:template>
                            </t:Column>
                            <t:Column width="130px" demandPopin="true" id="idProdReportProdCount" showSortMenuEntry="false"
                                                    minScreenWidth="Tablet" hAlign="End">
                                <Label text="Level" design="Bold" class="TableLabelColor" />
                                <t:template>
                                    <ObjectIdentifier text="{@level}" />
                                </t:template>
                            </t:Column>
                        </t:columns>
                    </t:TreeTable>
```